# onAuthStateChange not working in production (React-Express deployment problem)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, express

```
useEffect(() => {     
    console.log('outside auth state changed unsubscribe');
    const unsubscribe = () => {

        console.log('inside auth state changed unsubscribe');

        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (loggedUser: User | null) => {
            setUser(loggedUser)

            console.log('on auth state changed func user:', loggedUser);

            setLoading(false)
        })
    }
    console.log('user ::: after onAuthStateChanged', user);
    return () => {
        unsubscribe()
    }
}, [])
```

This is the code where the problem occurs.

In my react code everything that is related to firebase and socket works just fine in:

- the development environment and
- also in the production mode which is locally run by express after building the dist folder

But when I refresh it in the express server. this unsubscribe function does not run and the setLoading(false) is never invoked.
I have console.logged the code in different ways but it doesn't print the line below in build/production mode:

`console.log('inside auth state changed unsubscribe');`

my express code for running the clientside app is given below

```
const __dirname2 = path.resolve()

if (true) {
    // console.log( path.join(__dirname2, "/client/dist"));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname2, "/client/dist")))
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname2, "client", "dist", "index.html"))
    })
} else {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {

        console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
        res.send("API is running successfully")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const unsubscribe = () => {
  console.log('inside auth state changed unsubscribe');
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (loggedUser: User | null) => {
  // ...
```

You're creating a function named `unsubscribe`, and inside that you register for auth state changes. But you never call `unsubscribe`, so you never register. What you probably meant to do was this:

```
const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (loggedUser: User | null) => {
  setUser(loggedUser)
  console.log('on auth state changed func user:', loggedUser);
  setLoading(false)
});

return () => {
  console.log('unsubscribing');
  unsubscribe()
}
```

With this code you call `onAuthStateChange` right away, thus registering for the event. `onAuthStateChange` returns a function to you, which you can call later to unsubscribe.